# Use MapReduce or other distributed computation method for an analytics calculation?

Tags: dictionary, mapreduce, distributed-computing, reduce

Let's say I have three basic models: a User, a Company, and a Visit.   Every time a User goes to a Company, a Visit is recorded in this format `(user_id, company_id, visit_date)`.

I'd like to be able to calculate the average time between visits for a company.  Not visits overall, but specifically how long on average one of their customers waits before returning to the store.

For example, if one user visited on Tuesday, Wednesday, and Friday that gives one "gap" of one day, and one "gap" of two days => (1, 2).  If another user visited on Monday and Friday, that gives one gap of 4 days => (4).  If a third user visited only once, he should not be considered.  The average time between user visits for the company is (1 + 2 + 4) / 3 = 2.333 days.

If I have thousands of users, taps, and companies and I want to calculate a single figure for each company, how should I go about this?  I've only done basic MapReduce applications before and I can't figure out what my Map and Reduce steps would be to get this done.  Can anyone help me figure out a MapReduce in pseudocode?  Or is there some other method of distributed calculation I can reasonably perform?  For the record, I'd like to perform this operation on my database every night.

Answer (score 0):

The overly simplistic approach would be to have two job steps.

First job step has a mapper to write key values in the form "company:user" and "visit_date".  In the example above, the mapper would write something like:

```
"user1:companyA" -> "2012/07/16"
"user1:comapnyA" -> "2012/07/17"
"user1:comapnyA" -> "2012/07/19"
"user2:comapnyA" -> "2012/07/15"
"user2:comapnyA" -> "2012/07/19"
...
```

This means that each call to the reducer will pass all of the visits by a single user to a single company. That means that one call to the reducer will pass in:

```
"user1:companyA" -> {2012/07/16, 2012/07/17, 2012/07/19}
```

and another call will pass in:

```
"user2:companyA" -> {2012/07/15, 2012/07/19}
```

I'm assuming the set of dates (passed in as an Iterable value) is easily managed as you sort it, figure out the gaps and write a record for each gap as a key value pair in the form "company" and "gap".  For example, when passed:

```
"user1:companyA" -> {2012/07/16, 2012/07/17, 2012/07/19}
```

The first job's reducer will write to the context:

```
"companyA" -> 1
"compnayA" -> 2
```

The second job has a pass-through mapper that just passes the company/gap info on to the reducer.  Each call to the reducer gives an Iterable value of gaps for a specific company.  Iterate through the data to produce an average and write the key value pair in the form "company" and "average_gap".

If the original set of visits gets too big, we can talk about getting hadoop to do the sorting for you with some custom comparators.

Comment: I'm a little confused by what you're doing with the "gaps", can you elaborate?

Comment: The gaps are as you defined them: the difference in time between two consecutive visits by a user to a company.  I'll edit the answer some more